# Azure DevOps Service Connection with specific Service Principal via Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I created a Service Principal and an App Registration in my Azure Subscription using Terraform:

```
resource "azuread_application" "terraform_app" {
  display_name = "testbed"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "terraform" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.terraform_app.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  tags                         = ["HideApp", "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"]
}
```

I also created a certificate for the App Registration:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "terraform_application" {
  name         = "terraform-application"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.terraform_key_vault.id

  # ...
}
```

I'd like to either use this Service Principal or a new one here:

```
resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "devops" {
  project_id                = "HARD_CODED_ID"
  service_endpoint_name     = "ARM: ${data.azurerm_subscription.current.display_name}"

  azurerm_spn_tenantid      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.tenant_id
  azurerm_subscription_id   = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  azurerm_subscription_name = data.azurerm_subscription.current.display_name

  credentials {
    serviceprincipalid  = azuread_service_principal.terraform.id
    serviceprincipalkey = "?????"
  }
}
```

How can I use the existing certificate or create an SP Key to use for the `azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm.credentials` block?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I made a **gigantic** typo that I didn't notice:

```
resource "azuread_application_password" "terraform_app" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.terraform_app.object_id
  display_name          = "primary"
}

resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_azurerm" "devops" {
  project_id                = "HARD_CODED_ID"
  service_endpoint_name     = "ARM: ${data.azurerm_subscription.current.display_name}"
  description               = "Terraform Service Connection for infrastructure work"

  azurerm_spn_tenantid      = data.azurerm_subscription.current.tenant_id
  azurerm_subscription_id   = data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id
  azurerm_subscription_name = data.azurerm_subscription.current.display_name

  credentials {
    serviceprincipalid      = azuread_service_principal.terraform.object_id
    serviceprincipalkey     = azuread_application_password.terraform_app.value
  }
}
```